# SeDebugPrivilege issue on Windows 8.1 and windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, security, memory, reverse-engineering

a few days ago I posted a question about ReadProcessMemory not returning the correct value, now I been aware of why it worked on my windows 7 machine and not for windows 8.1 and windows 10, and that is SeDebugPriviledge. I did some research on it, and found a function to enable  privledges for it, it return that it has been a success.

```
    void sample()
{

    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tokenPriv;
    LUID luidDebug;
    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken) != FALSE)
    {
        if (LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luidDebug) != FALSE)
        {
            tokenPriv.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            tokenPriv.Privileges[0].Luid = luidDebug;
            tokenPriv.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
            if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tokenPriv, 0, NULL, NULL) != FALSE)
            {
                // Always successful, even in the cases which lead to OpenProcess failure
                cout << "SUCCESSFULLY CHANGED TOKEN PRIVILEGES" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "FAILED TO CHANGE TOKEN PRIVILEGES, CODE: " << GetLastError() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hToken);


}
```

But what happened next is that instead of printing out 0 in the console, it started printing out this negative number, -858993445. Then I decided to try it on a diffrent process, and a different computer, this time on windows 10 instead of windows 8.1, and the same exact number was printed, on three different processes and two different computers running two different OS's. I tried coding the program on windows 7 instead and putting it on a usb and running it on windows 8.1, it was then fully working. But when I coded it and debugged it, it didn't work. Does anyone have any experience with this issue and how I can bypass this, I know it is there for security reasons, but I need PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS for practising reverse engineering.

> DISCLAIMER: THIS IS NOT FOR HACKING OR MALWARE DEVELOPMENT PURPOSES, IF I WANTED TO CHEAT IN A VIDEO GAME I COULD JUST DOWNLOAD A CHEAT ONLINE

EDIT:  I should add that my computer can't find secpol.msc

The ReadProcessMemory function:

```
    int main()
{
    int points;
    sample();
    DWORD pID;
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, ("Call of Duty®: Black Ops"));
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pID);
    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pID);
    ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)0x1C0A6C8, &points, sizeof(points), 0);
    cout << points << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167504/discussion-on-question-by-pasta-dealer-sedebugprivilege-issue-on-windows-8-1-and).

Answer (score 0):

I did no changes to my code or computer, but out of no where it started working again, strange.